# How to return groups sharing comman values in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My dataframe somewhat looks like this:

```
df:
Col1 Col2
A     123
B     154
A     123
C     199
A     201
B     199
C     123
```

If , I group by Col1, then I want to display all groups sharing common value of Col2.

The output currently looks like:

```
123  [A,C,A]
199  [B,C]
```

But, it should always remove duplicate 'col1' from the list if it has any. Hence, the output should look like:

```
123  [A,C]
199  [B,C]
```

Here the duplicate value A displayed only once as duplicate is removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` col2 then

```
df.groupby('Col2').Col1.apply(list).loc[lambda x : x.str.len()>1]
Out[350]: 
Col2
123    [A, C]
199    [C, B]
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: What's the reason for `.loc[lambda x : x.str.len()>1]` ?

Comment: @jpp cause he mentioned *all groups sharing common value of Col2*

Comment: OK, I guess the wording of the question is poor. `sharing common value of Col2` just means `groupby` + `apply(list)`. What OP wants to do (possibly) is remove all rows where list is of length one.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Can you help me with the edited question?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to filter only for values mapping to more than one letter, you can use `pd.Series.duplicated` followed by `groupby`:

```
res = df.loc[df['Col2'].duplicated(keep=False)]\
        .groupby('Col2')['Col1'].apply(list)

print(res)

Col2
123    [A, C]
199    [C, B]
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Can you help me with the edited question?